# Problems with Ajax request to HTTPS over API

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, heroku

I am trying to deploy my first React app through Heroku. It works completely fine when running in local environment, but when I deploy it can't complete a request to The Movie DB API with the errors:

```
The page at 'https://boiling-escarpment-83243.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/list?api_key='. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

and

```
{"status_code":7,"status_message":"Invalid API key: You must be granted a valid key."}
```

Again, there has been no trouble with the API key in local. Originally the base_uri in the package I am using points to an http URL, but I updated it to be https (and tested the https route and it seems to be supported: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550). Here is my non-working app: https://boiling-escarpment-83243.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Did you register an app for both domains? Some API's use domain specific api keys

Comment: @charlietfl it didn't seem like you needed to register domains with that api for read-only apps, but maybe I'm wrong....

Answer (score 0):

Silly question: did you update your request URL to https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550? Looks like the request is still http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550.

Comment: Yeah I did. I'm also confused why it's still requesting http. And I forced commit so it's definitely updated.

Comment: Can you post a little more of your code? Can we see where you are making the request?